# How to verify app launched using monkey runner?

Tags: monkeyrunner

Is there a way to verify app launched successfully using monkey runner? Other than using image verification. May be using dumpsys?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the result of

```
dumpsys activity activities
```

then you should find your Activity at the top of the stack, if was launched successfully.